# Using fixtures with Clearance in Rails 4 for unit test user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, fixtures, minitest, clearance

I'm using [Clearance](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance) for authentication in my Rails application.
I'm using the default Minitest stack. Clearance by default only use email and password fields so i add a `name` field and now i want to unit test the model to do some checks.

This is my test so far.

```ruby
test "should not save without name" do
  user = User.new
  user.email = "john@sample.com"
  user.password = "foobar"
  assert_not user.valid?
end
```

And this is my model validation.

```ruby
validates :name, presence: true
```

Everything works great and the test fails as expected. The problem is that i wanted to use a user fixture to clean a little my test.

One viable approach could be

```yaml
john:
  name: John
  email: john@sample.com
  password: foobar
```

But then the test execution fails saying that there isn't a field called password. Indeed the field is called `encrypted_password`. I can create one using the `BCrypt::Password.create` method but again, another error raises telling me that `remember_token` can't be null, i suspect that the same happens with the `confirmation_token` field.
So my question is.

Is there any way that i can create a rails fixture to use those data in my test using the clearance authentication library ?

**Update:**
To clarify the fixture example due to the correct answer the result fixture is:

```yaml
john:
  name: John
  email: john@sample.com
  encrypted_password: <%= BCrypt::Password.create("foobar", cost: 4) %>
  remember_token: <%= Clearance::Token.new %>
```

And that's it, it works like charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the User ActiveRecord API is used to create the object, all of the required fields should be set appropriately. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like this happens with fixtures - or at least it's not happening for you (I don't use fixtures, so I'm not sure).

You can set any required tokens to: `Clearance::Token.new`, which is what Clearance uses to generate tokens.

Comment: Yeahh, that was the missing part, is working fine now, Thanks.